# Cakephp 3 pagination - how get active link

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, how can i configure pagination to show active link.

no i have something like this:

When i am on 3 page, i cant style this button to show user his position.
My template for pagination looks like this:

```
$config = [
'number' => '<li><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
'current' => '<li><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',];
```

i have tried cakephp3 docs, but without success.

Answer (score 2):

This easy way is working.

```
$config = [
'number' => '<li><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
'current' => '<li class="current"><a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
```

];